# omniauth callback timeout

Tags: timeout, omniauth

I used sample of https://github.com/igaiga/omniauth-sample, it just stucked at the callback phase. 
I've also tested some other samples, the result were same.

```
Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?state=118c21d7ea5675990e0a5e8a876f041f59dbc9a925f94754&code=AQDp93hH-WQor4ZQ8S_ZIGw0dTARw5vPMmkNAiRW9Ql8n7-fny0R5Du88InAILPbXUmdwWh_MyMpZzHzhO2YSlDXeMclSdyDfQQbtlFqixnYgpFt_3Sx5DETKIAYj2amRhK6JaNvxT1ffXgJ6qbMfHUbXlaerFWep60RVHBqwdA6tS-AoPQBNbKSA52-YAhj9-McGoEl4LQi4PGkIpVZu9IV" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-07 16:51:24 +0800

Errno::ETIMEDOUT (Operation timed out - SSL_connect):
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
  /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
  faraday (0.8.7) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:75:in `perform_request'
  faraday (0.8.7) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.7) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.7) lib/faraday/connection.rb:247:in `run_request'
  oauth2 (0.8.1) lib/oauth2/client.rb:88:in `request'
  oauth2 (0.8.1) lib/oauth2/client.rb:131:in `get_token'
  oauth2 (0.8.1) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:99:in `build_access_token'
  omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:73:in `block in build_access_token'
  omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:174:in `with_authorization_code!'
  omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:73:in `build_access_token'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:74:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:219:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:175:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is I'm behind the GFW of china. For some reason goagent does not help in this problem, and vpn only helps in case of facebook. The good news is when I deployed the codes to heroku it works for both facebook and twitter.